# What is the difference between "Design Function" and "Objective Function"?

Tags: optimization

What is the difference between "*[Design Function](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=kKWs51HLLA8C&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=%22design%20function%22%20optimization&source=bl&ots=pgopL0tHIn&sig=Ld447r6KlDsSdp88yak3pwlU1GY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpr--6sY3eAhUTcCsKHXhYC7sQ6AEwB3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22design%20function%22%20optimization&f=false)*" and "*[Objective Function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoJQS10Ewn4&pbjreload=10)*" in the study of Optimization?

Comment: "to minimize **some** *design function*". This implies that we may have more than one function used to "describe" (design) the problem. We select one of them : the *objective function* to be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, design functions are the objective function and constraints for the optimization problem.  Objective function is just the design function being minimized (or maximized).

I am not used to seeing such terminology, but this appears to be what is intended in the link.